# Why does 8250 UART driver not wake up TTY if more than 256 characters are pending?

Tags: linux, console, tty, history, serial-console

What is the motivation of this if-condition in `void serial8250_tx_chars(struct uart_8250_port *up)`?

```
if (uart_circ_chars_pending(xmit) < WAKEUP_CHARS)
    uart_write_wakeup(port);
```

It has been there ever since Linux 1.1.13 (May 1994) and repeats in most UART drivers.

Background: customized Linux 3.4.91, embedded system on ARMv7, UART port 0 is configured for 38400 baud, 16 byte FIFO for i/o. None of this can be changed in our setup.

When printf-ing *very* heavily on the console via UART, the internal 4kB-buffer (`UART_XMIT_SIZE`) fills up and then *stalls* the user-space process until the buffer is emptied (which takes one second at 38400 baud!). Then this behavior repeats. This is because function `n_tty_write()` goes to sleep when the buffer is full, and is not woken up for a long time because of the questionable condition above.

I would find it more natural and efficient if this check was simply removed. Then the printfs would fill up the buffer as quickly as they can, and *then continue at the speed at which the buffer is being emptied*, rather than the burst-processing I am observing.

It works fine in my environment but surely I am missing or misunderstanding something. There must be a reason for the current implementation. Are there any side effects if I remove that condition?

As a side-question: are there configuration options to tune this behavior, e.g. to have printf always return immediately and discard the output if the buffer is full?

Comment: Without knowing too much about this, my hunch is this: This is an ordinary Linux serial console setup. I worked with those on the standard x86 hardware. For direct serial connections, I always had to use hardware flow control. Might be an idea.

Comment: There is likely an efficiency difference.  Why not just set WAKEUP_CHARS to  something like UART_XMIT_SIZE - 128?

Comment: @JamesYoungman In fact, that's what I ended up doing as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It's an efficiency measure.  The CPU runs so much faster than the serial port that if the kernel let the userspace process run every time there was a little bit of room in the buffer, it would end up making a trip to userspace and back for every single byte of data.  That's very wasteful of CPU time:

```
$ time dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1 count=10000000
10000000+0 records in
10000000+0 records out
10000000 bytes (10 MB, 9.5 MiB) copied, 5.95145 s, 1.7 MB/s

real    0m5.954s
user    0m1.960s
sys     0m3.992s

$ time dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1000 count=10000
10000+0 records in
10000+0 records out
10000000 bytes (10 MB, 9.5 MiB) copied, 0.011041 s, 906 MB/s

real    0m0.014s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.012s
```

The above test isn't even reading and writing a real device: the whole time difference is how often the system is bouncing between userspace and kernelspace.

If userspace doesn't want to be held up, it can use non-blocking I/O, or it can check use a `select()` call to see if there's room to write to the device... and if there's not, it can dump the remainder into a buffer of its own and continue processing.  Admittedly, that does complicate things, since now you have a buffer that you have to flush... but if you're using stdio, that's generally true anyway.

Comment: This supports @James' comment about efficiency above. Now it makes much more sense to me. Thanks, also for the numbers!

Comment: It should be noted that since kernel 2.6, this question references code which often appears in lower layer drivers (e.g. a UART driver).  These drivers provide the higher layer, serial_core, the means to interact with hardware.  It is the serial core which actually interacts with user space (unless the hardware driver implements it's own ioctls or something similar).  I believe the respondents answer still holds.